Setting duplex mode with SetPrinter() is not working
I try to set duplex (two-sided) mode on my printer, but calling SetPrinter() is not working:
bool SetDuplexMode(HANDLE hPrinter, short duplexMode) {
    PRINTER_INFO_2* pInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0;
    GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded);
    pInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)malloc(dwNeeded);
    if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, (LPBYTE)pInfo, dwNeeded, &dwNeeded)) {
        free(pInfo);
        return false;
    }

    DEVMODE* pDevMode = pInfo->pDevMode;
    if (!pDevMode) {
        free(pInfo);
        return false;
    }

    pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_DUPLEX;
    pDevMode->dmDuplex = duplexMode;

    if (!SetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, (LPBYTE)pInfo, 0)) {
        std::wcout << L"SetPrinter not working" << L'\n';
        free(pInfo);
        return false;
    }

    free(pInfo);
    return true;
}

I have this message :

SetPrinter not working


Does your printer support double-sided printing to begin with? Have you tried calling DeviceCapabilities(DC_DUPLEX) on the printer to make sure it reports that duplex is supported?

Yes, I asked this before, is supported. bool duplexSupported = (pInfo->pDevMode->dmFields & DM_DUPLEX); return true

I tried bool duplexSupported = DeviceCapabilties(..., NULL, DM_DUPLEX, NULL, NULL) ; and return 1

According to Q140285: How To Modify Printer Settings by Using SetPrinter:

Also, because modifying fields in the device-independent part of DEVMODE may also effect changes in the device-dependent part, you need to call DocumentProperties() before calling SetPrinter() in order to make a consistent DEVMODE structure for SetPrinter().

You also have to take into account that GetPrinter() may return a NULL DEVMODE* pointer, in which case you have to call DocumentProperties() to get a DEVMODE before you can make any changes.
You should also change pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_DUPLEX; to pDevMode->dmFields = DM_DUPLEX; before calling SetPrinter(), so that it knows you are changing only 1 field and not every field that GetPrinter() gave you.
With that said, try something more like the following (you are using C++, so I'm adding std::vector for better/safer memory management):
#include <vector>

bool SetDuplexMode(HANDLE hPrinter, short duplexMode)
{
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0;
    if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, nullptr, 0, &dwNeeded))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            std::wcout << L"GetPrinter failed\n";
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (dwNeeded == 0)
        return false;

    std::vector<BYTE> infoBuffer(dwNeeded);

    if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, infoBuffer.data(), dwNeeded, &dwNeeded))
    {
        std::wcout << L"GetPrinter failed\n";
        return false;
    }

    PRINTER_INFO_2* pInfo = reinterpret_cast<PRINTER_INFO_2*>(infoBuffer.data());

    DEVMODE* pDevMode = pInfo->pDevMode;
    std::vector<BYTE> devModeBuffer;

    if (!pDevMode)
    {
        LONG lNeeded = DocumentProperties(nullptr, hPrinter, pInfo->pPrinterName, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
        if (lNeeded <= 0)
        {
            std::wcout << L"DocumentProperties failed\n";
            return false;
        }

        devModeBuffer.resize(lNeeded);
        pDevMode = reinterpret_cast<DEVMODE*>(devModeBuffer.data());

        if (DocumentProperties(nullptr, hPrinter, pInfo->pPrinterName, pDevMode, nullptr, DM_OUT_BUFFER) != IDOK)
        {
            std::wcout << L"DocumentProperties failed\n";
            return false;
        }

        pInfo->pDevMode = pDevMode;
    }

    if (!(pDevMode->dmFields & DM_DUPLEX))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Printer does not support duplex mode\n";
        return false;
    }

    pDevMode->dmFields = DM_DUPLEX;
    pDevMode->dmDuplex = duplexMode;

    pInfo->pSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (DocumentProperties(nullptr, hPrinter, pInfo->pPrinterName, pDevMode, pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER) != IDOK)
    {
        std::wcout << L"DocumentProperties failed\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (!SetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(pInfo), 0))
    {
        std::wcout << L"SetPrinter failed\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


It work now, but when I launch StartDocPrinter(), my printer print pages one sided ?

I can't answer that, and I've never even heard of StartDocPrinter() before. Typically most people use StartDoc(), etc instead.

It's strange DocumentProperties must be use with StartDocPrinter() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions
